# Shortcut to execute shell scipt?

Tags: bash, scripts, executable, symbolic-link, alias

I'm trying to create a shortcut that will run a .sh file deep in some directory without having to navigating to the absolute path.

I have tried using aliases, which did not work as. 
Using soft/hard links, they did not work too as there are certain dependencies in that directory which the shell script reference to.

Anyone has any idea how to `./` a file without having to traverse down that absolute path?

The alias I have tried is :

```
alias minecraft='/var/www/owncloud/data/admin/files/Spigot/start.sh'
```

I have tried the Path variant by adding `PATH=/var/www/owncloud/data/admin/files/Spigot:"$PATH"` into  `~/.bashrc`.

Which then brings the message :

```
Error: Unable to access jarfile spigot.jar
```

I'm using a cli version of Ubuntu if it helps, so no Nautilus.

Comment: Add the absolute path to that directory to `PATH` environmental variable....BTW whats the problem you are having with alias?

Comment: we can not really help much without more information. post your alias. post the commands you ran to make links. post the path to you .sh . Post your $PATH

Comment: You could run it with the absolute path /full/path/to/my/script.sh entered as command for the link/launcher. Then add a line `cd /full/path/to/my/` at the beginning of your script (after #! /bin/bash) to make sure that all relative paths are looked up from the directory the script is located in.

Comment: See my answer (wherein alternatives using `cd` are also given).

Comment: In a launcher, set the `Exec=` line to: `Exec=sh -c "cd /path/to/scriptfolder&&./script.sh"` (Ah, @muru indeed a perfect dupe)

Comment: Hi I have edited the quesiton to contain more information.

Comment: You didn't setup your alias correctly, see my updated answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are getting the

```
Error: Unable to access jarfile spigot.jar
```

Errormessage because the script are using your bash environment working directory when it is executing. The script is probably executing `java -jar spigot.jar` where spigot.jar file must reside in the same directory. Since youre scripts environment is pointing at another directory the file cannot be found.

To fix this, edit your `/var/www/owncloud/data/admin/files/Spigot/start.sh` file and add this line just above the command where it is executing java.

```
cd "$( dirname "${BASH_SOURCE[0]}" )"
```

This command changes the current executing directory for the script to the directory it resides.

The result should be something like:

```
 #!/bin/bash

 cd "$( dirname "${BASH_SOURCE[0]}" )"
 java -jar spigot.jar
```

Then you can use the alias you mentioned in your question, or probably along with many of the other answers that is here.

Good luck!

Comment: This worked for me. I wasted a bunch of hours trying to create a shortcut for a java app. Turned out that the relative paths in `run.sh` were not being resolved correctly when the app was run using a launcher.

Answer (score 1):

You didn't setup your alias correctly, you should setup it like so: `alias minecraft='sh /var/www/owncloud/data/admin/files/Spigot/start.sh'`

Answer (score 0):

To get rid of the "./" expression for your script, You must have to set the custom path for your scripts in PATH variable. You can do it either using the export Command ( which will set up the variable under current running environment) or as below (for permanent solution)

To do so; Edit the **.bashrc** file in your home directory with your favorite Editor

> `vi .bashrc`

at the end of the file you can paste the following code.

```
#custom variable
export PATH=$PATH:/$HOME/bin:/var/www/owncloud/data/admin/files/Spigot/
```

***Above command sets up the additonal paths for your script file location, in this case your .sh script in Spigot folder.***

One thing you must remember while exporting the path is either you have to copy the contents of existing PATH variable into a file or in a text file using other editor you can do `echo $PATH >> variables.txt`

Reason why I'm saying so is if in case you lost the variable path, you wont be able to run other commands at all with aliases.

Finally: type
 `exec bash`

I have tested it hope it works fine for you as well. You should also be able to run the script without typing the full path. It should work as  **start.sh**

Good Luck!

Comment: Thanks for the answer, however I'm running into the error "Error: Unable to access jarfile spigot.jar". Any idea why this might happen? This occurs even using other methods like symlinks and functions.

Comment: looks like the .jar file is a library file and you have to export it to the variable called `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`, not sure if this is the answer to the question,but give it a try

Comment: But your original problem should be fixed.